# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method'

Tags: mysql, laravel-6

I don't really understand why this **@method('PUT')** is doing Unknown column '_method'in my SQL. I will show you all the code that's possibly the reason of this error below. Laravel version 6.2.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: update `setups` set `_method` = PUT, `id` = 1,
>   `image` = admitad-e1504616712278.png, `meta_title` = testing,
>   `address` = testing, `contact` = testing@testing, `email` = testing,
>   `social` = ["testing","testing"], `updated_at` = 2019-12-29 15:40:21
>   where `_method` = PUT)

**2019_12_23_171326_create_setups_table.php**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('setups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('meta_title');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('contact');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('social');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
<form class="card-body" method="POST" action="{{ route('setups.update', $data->id) }}">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
<input type="hidden" name="tbl" value="{{encrypt('setups')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $data->id }}">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group" style="left: 5px; padding: 30px 0 30px">
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" style="display: none">
      <img id="output" width="150" style="box-shadow: 0px 16px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.17);"/>
      <label class="card-title" for="file" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 10px 0 0px">Upload Logo</label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="bmd-label-floating">Site title</label>
          <input type="text" name="meta_title" value="{{ $data -> meta_title }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="bmd-label-floating">Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="address" value="{{ $data -> address }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="bmd-label-floating">Contant number</label>
          <input type="email" name="contact" value="{{ $data -> contact }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="bmd-label-floating">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" value="{{ $data -> email }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="socialGroup">
        @foreach($socials as $social)
        <div class="form-group socialField">
        <label class="bmd-label-floating">Social Links</label>
          <input type="text" name="social[]" value="{{ $social }}" class="form-control">
          <a href="#" class="addField"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        <div class="alert alert-danger" id="socialError">
        <p><strong>Sorry! </strong>You've reached the max number for social links form.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update Profile</button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </form>
```

**SetupController.php**

```
public function update(Request $request, Setup $setup)
{
    $data = Input::except('_token', 'submit');
    $tbl = decrypt($data['tbl']);
    unset ($data['tbl']);

    if(!empty($data['image'])){
      if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        $data['image'] = $this->upload($data['image'], $tbl);
      }
    }

    $data['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    DB::table($tbl)->where(key($data), reset($data))->update($data);

    session::flash('message','SetupController updated successfully!!!');
    return redirect()->route('setups.index');
}
```

**web.php**

Route::resource('setups','SetupController');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@method('PUT')
```

always print

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

into source html, if you don't want to use this you can remove or you want  eliminate them add one more value in your code :

```
$data = Input::except('_token', 'submit','_method');
```

Comment: Is there another way sir? Instead of using the @method('PUT') ?